# draftjs how to initiate an editor with content from an array object of html

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I want to create an editor which will initiate an html element with the styling..

```
 const contents = [
    {
      "text": "Sample text",
      "HTML": "<p style='text-align: center;'><span style='font-size:3em;'><strong>Sample text</strong></span></p>"
    },
    {
      "text": "Sample text2",
      "HTML": "<p style='text-align: center;'><span style='font-size:3em;'><strong>Sample text2</strong></span></p>"
    }
]
```

then I map it to get the html key then set it in the state

```
const content = contents.map(element => htmlToDraft(element.HTML))
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(content)
}
```

Then rendering the editor multiple times by the number of elements of html key in the state:

```
this.state.editorState.map((element,index) => {
   return 
          <Editor
            defaultEditorState = {element}
            onEditorStateChange = {this.onEditorStateChange}
            key={index}
          />
})
```

When I run it, it throws an error contentState.getBlockMap is not a function

Comment: here's my codesanbox if you guys wanna replicate the error https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-tdd-2b15g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: here's your fixed codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-curran-x3bc9?file=/src/App.js